# Offset satellite timseries data

Tags: time-series, cdo-climate, satellite

I have been working with the PERSIANN data validation and I have noticed that the data collection time has a different time than the stations that I have in the data observed in the field.

Is it possible that with `CDO` an offset can be made on the satellite data so that the series coincides temporarily with the observed data?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function `shifttime` to change the timestamp...  Examples usages:

```
cdo shifttime,-1day in.nc out.nc

cdo shifttime,1hour in.nc out.nc
```